# PropertyChangedEvent subscription happens some time after binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am working through my first WPF app and have come across a strange behavior. I believe the following sequence of events is happening.

in my MainWindow constructor I create an instance of my ViewModel which interfaces INotifyPropertyChanged and set it to the data context

In my ViewModel constructor I create instances of objects that rely on io so most of the are async and use the event model. I have implemented changed events in these objects and my constructor subscribes to these events with methods that just call the PropertyChanged delegate of the ViewModel

I have noticed instances where on application startup the objects in ViewModel will fire there change event fast  (happens when connection is quick) and when it goes to call the PropertyChanged event delegate it is null. I check for this condition so my application carries on but the state won't update until the object reports a change again.

It seems that there can be a delay between a bindings initial read of a property and subscription to the PropertyChanged event.

Is this documented/known and is there a way to work with it.

Comment: It helps to see some example code to help diagnose the issue. In your constructor are you setting your data context before or after InitializeComponent() is called? What's being initialized in your view model constructor? How are you defining your properties?

Comment: The times I've seen this happen it's usually come down to either not specifying `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` or the UI thread being tied up with other tasks (like pulling data from the db).

Comment: @MDK: I am right to assume that you call async call in your constructor? One suggestion: Don't do it, it cause all kind of weird behavior and in constructor you can't `await` `async` calls. I guess your code finishes, before the ViewModel is completely initialized and assigned to the View's `DataContext`, so the view didn't subscribe yet to the `PropertyChanged` event. Use a navigation pattern, like `INavigationAware` and `INavigationService` in Prism MVVM Framework or similar implementations